# My discord.js bot wont kick people and no errors in the console

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a command that kicks people, unfortunately, it doesn't work and no errors in the console, when I type -kick without mentioning anyone, the expected message comes, but when I mention someone it doesn't kick them.

Here is my code in my command handler:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'kick',
  decription: 'Kick command',
  execute(message, args) {
    if (!message.guild) return;

    const user = message.mentions.users.first();

    if (user) {
      const member = message.guild.member(user);

      if (member) {
        member
          .kick()
          .then(() => {
            message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
            console.error(err);
          });
      } else {
        message.reply("That user isn't in this guild!");
      }
    } else {
      message.reply("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
    };
  }
}
```

EDIT: here is my main file code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const keepAlive = require("./server");
const client = new Discord.Client();
const prefix = ('-');
const fs = require('fs');

client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`logged in as ${client.user.tag}`);
});

client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs
  .readdirSync('./commands/')
  .filter((file) => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
  const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);

  client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) 
    return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split("/ +/");
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if (command === 'help') {
    client.commands.get('help').execute(message, args);
  } else if (command === 'clear') {
    client.commands.get('clear').help(message,args);
  } else if(command === 'ban') {
    client.commands.get('ban').execute(message, args);
  } else if(command === 'kick') {
    client.commands.get('kick').execute(message);
  } else if(command === 'mute') {
    client.commands.get('mute').execute(message,args);
  }
});

keepAlive();
client
  .login("TOKEN")
  .catch(console.error);
```

Comment: Can you explain what happens when you type -kick and mention someone. Do you get an error message? And if so, what message are you getting?

Comment: So when i type -kick without mentioning anyone, the expected message is sent by the bot saying that i have to mention someone. but when i type -kick when mentioning someone the bot doesnt kick the person and it doesnt send any message to the channel or the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by editing my code a bit. I also moved the code from my command handler to my main file. Here is the code for anyone who needs it.

```
else if(message.content.startsWith("-kick")) {
   message.content.split("-kick ")[1]
   if (!message.guild) return;
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
if (member) {
  member
    .kick()
    .then(() => {
      message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${member.user.tag}`);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
      console.error(err);
    });
} else {
  message.reply("You didn't mention a member to kick!");
 };
}
```

I only added the following piece of code:

```
message.content.split("-kick ")[1]
```

EDIT: I figured out what was wrong

```
 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split("/ +/");
```

I needed to remove the quotation marks at the end, so it is basically like this:

```
 const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
```

Answer (score 0):

> args is not defined

This just means that the parameter `args` to your `execute` function is unnecessary here and you could remove it.

`guild.member()` does not exist, use `guild.members.resolve(user.id)` instead.

Also if you're just accessing a member of a guild, you should use `message.mentions.members` instead.

So in the end it would look something like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  name: 'kick',
  decription: 'Kick command',
  execute(message) {
    if (!message.guild) return;
    const member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (member) {
      member
        .kick()
        .then(() => {
          message.reply(`Successfully kicked ${member.user.tag}`);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          message.reply('I was unable to kick the member');
          console.error(err);
        });
    } else {
      message.reply("You didn't mention a member to kick!");
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: Mrcoding8, i copy pasted your code directly into my command handler and it still doesnt work. and the same issue happens. I am new to coding so its probably some silly mistake. Thanks for helping anyway. I will edit my post and put my main file code in it, maybe something is wrong there.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript has a feature that tells you if you declared an unnecessary variable (you never used the variable). You could remove it, or ignore it. Your code will work either way.

For example, using this code, TypeScript will tell you `b is declared but its value is never read`

```js
const a = 1
const b = 2
console.log(a)
//b is not used anywhere except for the declaration
```

**Why is your code not working?**

You are using `Guild.member`. This relies on cache and is deprecated. Use `message.mentions.members.first()` instead to directly retrieve the member

```js
const member = message.mentions.members.first();
```